# Send thank you message with mail_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, mail-form

I'm currently using mail_form + simple_form gems to send an email to myself after a user submits a "contact us" form on my site. I then also submit the fields to a database. Everything here is working fine.

I'd like to be able to send a second email to the user's email address with a "Thank you" message and some other copy directly after submission. I know a message could be posted with flash, but an email to the user would be better in my case.

Can someone please provide some guidance on how this would be done based on the code below? Thanks!

Model: page.rb

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MailForm::Delivery
  attribute :name,      :validate => true
  attribute :company
  attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i
  attribute :message
  attribute :nickname,  :captcha  => true

  def headers
    {
      :subject => "New Lead from Composites First",
      :to => "myemail@myemail.com",
      :from => "myemail@myemail.com"
    }
  end
end
```

Controller: pages_controller.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def basicform
    @page = Page.new
  end 

  def create
    @page = Page.create(page_params)
    if @page.save   
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to '/' }
        format.json { } 
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { }
        format.json { }
      end
    end
    @page.request = request
    if @page.deliver
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Cannot send message.'
      format.html { redirect_to '/' }
    end
  end

  private 

  def page_params
      params.require(:page).permit(:name, :company, :email, :message)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `after_create` callback to trigger thank you email.

In Page model write callback as below:

```
after_create :send_thank_you_email

def send_thank_you_email
  email = self.from 
  MyMailer.send_thank_you_email(email).deliver_now
end
```

Now in `MyMailer` write `send_thank_you_email` action and create mailer view for thank you mail. Hope this helps. Thanks!